# Microsoft Word formatting Strong format

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

I want to replace Word formatting from Strong to simple text. It works with all formats except "Strong". Do you have any ideas?

Here is video.

[image: video]

Comment: Thanks, i recorded here https://streamable.com/dv8lz

Comment: Valid question! +1

Answer (score 1):

In your example video you are searching for *"Font: 29 pt"* and replacing it with *"Style: Normal"*.

Microsoft Word has two different types of style, *"Paragraph style"* and *"Character style"*. If you right click a style and enter edit dialog you can see the type for each style:

[image: modify style dialog]

The style *"Normal"* is a paragraph style. Setting a new paragraph style only replaces another paragraph style like *"Heading 1"*.

*"Strong"* is a character style and can be applied on top of the current paragraph style. Setting a character style will not replace the paragraph style.

You can search like you do for *"Font: 29 pt"* and replace with *"Font: Not Strong"* (can be selected in the font dialog under style). This keeps font size and any other font attributes - except for font weight.

Comment: I try to grasp this. So what is this exactly; an overwrite of styles then? I try to find more examples. Word is legendary, also in terms of its secret language and meanings.

Comment: Update. Now the "strong" is catching the "Title". Trying to understand this.